# Error ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py) in linux

Tags: python, linux, collections, ordereddict

does anyone know how to solve this problem?
I'm trying to run this code https://github.com/alexjc/neural-enhance

But I am having problems with the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeanpierre/Descargas/neural-enhance-master/enhance.py", line 123, in <module>
    import theano, theano.tensor as T
  File "/home/jeanpierre/Descargas/neural-enhance-master/pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from theano.configdefaults import config
  File "/home/jeanpierre/Descargas/neural-enhance-master/pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 16, in <module>
    from theano.configparser import (AddConfigVar, BoolParam, ConfigParam, EnumStr,
  File "/home/jeanpierre/Descargas/neural-enhance-master/pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 15, in <module>
    from theano.compat import configparser as ConfigParser
  File "/home/jeanpierre/Descargas/neural-enhance-master/pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/theano/compat/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from collections import OrderedDict, MutableMapping as DictMixin
ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

try testing

```
 from collections.abc import OrderedDict, MutableMapping as DictMixin.
```

But, I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderedDict' from 'collections.abc' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/abc.py)
```

.
help me, please!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

that's python 3.10 change that broke it, use python 3.9 for that

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1718878